# visual studio doesn't detect my python file

Tags: javascript, python, html, .net, pyscript

Im trying to use my `main.py` file in a `<script>` tag, but it doesn't appear to work like js files do. I tried including it like this [Searching python file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tttCS.png)

```html
<script type="py" scr="~/py/main.py"></script>
```

and like this [Js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhAp4.png)

```html
<script type="py" scr="~/js/"></script>
```

Even using the file path doesn't work

I'm using pyscript to use python on html
What can i do?

I was trying to use the file path directly. I get this error: `Fetching from URL /py/main.py failed with the error 404 (). Are your filename and path correct?`
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVQ8v.png)

Comment: Have you already run a pyscript example file, one you got from [here](https://pyscript.com/@examples), this way? Maybe I'm not up on all that VSCode can do because I don't use it but normally you use a code editor to develop your HTML page, post it, and then use a browser to test it. Read the error carefully. 'Fetching from URL /py/main.py failed'. If you open your browser and put that URL in your browser it probably fails, too ,right? VSCode isn't a browser & doesn't have a HTML preview, see 'Does VS Code have HTML preview?', and so I'm not sure what you are expecting?